# Rails 6 ActiveAdmin CSV Export does not maintain filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We're using Activeadmin to manage a number of data tables within our app.  One function we want to use is CSV download, but, the CSV download links generated by ActiveAdmin do not respect filters.

In one table we have 8+ million records.  We want to be able to filter by text, and then export the CSV of the filtered list.  Filtering works fine in browser, but if you click CSV - you get a CSV of the entire table.

What is the trick for getting ActiveAdmin to use filters during exports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve this once to, this could be a way. I made an action_item like:

```
action_item :special, only: :index do
  link_to 'Custom CSV with filters and scopes', custom_csv_admin_your_own_pluralized_resource_name_here_path(params.permit!.slice(:q, :scope))
end

collection_action :custom_csv, :method => :get do
  collection = find_collection
  # here you can iterate over collection (maybe  in batches) and generate CSV
end
```

You may want to read this file in the GEM source:

```
lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb
```

at: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb